# Why "Select * into targettable from sourcetable “ is faster than “insert into targettable select * from sourcetable

Tags: sql-server

This title is the question. I am curious to know the answer. Someone told

select into is minimally logged in Simple recovery model database ... I didn't get into it at all.

**Excerpt from Microsoft:**

*The amount of logging for SELECT...INTO depends on the recovery model in effect for the database. Under the simple recovery model or bulk-logged recovery model, bulk operations are minimally logged. With minimal logging, using the SELECT… INTO statement can be more efficient than creating a table and then populating the table with an INSERT statement*

Seeking help

Thanks

Comment: What database are you using? What structures are the tables? How did you measure that one is faster than the other?

Comment: I would be surprised if there was any difference on a well written DBMS.

Comment: Database: Sql server 20005... and I heard this.. even i am not 100% sure... I am looking for the what other peoples says.. As I mentioned that someone told me this..

Comment: Found a link that confirms that `SELECT INTO` can be [minimally logged](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;Q272093) when not using Full Recovery.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A couple of ideas/theories:

**SELECT INTO...** lets the RDBMS determine sort order based on order of your original table.  If you insert into an existing table, there may be a sort needed to match a clustered or nonclustered index(es).

**No Indexes** - when you `SELECT INTO...` the RDBMS knows for certain there are no pre-existing indexes to update.

**No Contention** - since the table you are inserting into does not exist, SQL Server doesn't need to worry about row-level locking or contention handling.  Nothing else can reference the table you create since it doesn't exist.

*All that being said, there are other ways to insert into a table very quickly.*

- Make sure your clustered index keys match when possible.  This means there is no on-the-fly sorting
- Disable all non-clustered indexes.  Self-explanatory.
- Set recovery mode to simple and trace flag 610 to `ON`.  Use the `TABLOCK` hint on your target table and `NOLOCK` hint on your source table.

For example, assume tablea and tableb have the same clustered index:

```
INSERT INTO TableB WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT <Columns>
FROM TableA WITH (NOLOCK)
```

In my experience this is faster than using `SELECT INTO...` and then creating the clustered index afterwards.  Please note this can also work on a table that **already has data in it** which is a much more useful scenario.

**EDIT:**

[Here's a fantastically detailed whitepaper from MS for data load performance in Sql Server 2008.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070%28SQL.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Very thorough answer JNK. Also, when implemented correctly and the recovery model is not full, a simple SSIS data flow task can be faster than either of these. Why? Both of the above will issue an exclusive lock (Read is multi-thread but write is single thread). As long as a table lock is used with the destination adapter, SSIS will use a bulk update lock (Both read and write are multi-thread).

Comment: Please never use nolock hint on source. It is unrelated to this scenario, as it more of a concurrency related hint, and can introduce phantom reads, dups.