# Will a MERGE between two tables ever be faster than a DROP and SELECT INTO on the second table?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, data-synchronization, merge, query-performance

Is there a scenario where it's faster for synchronizing the data from TableA to TableB by using a MERGE query as opposed to dropping TableB and doing a SELECT * INTO TableB FROM TableA?

Comment: In my specific case, there's actually no indexes on TableB at the time of the SELECT INTO, but a single unique clustered (PK) and a single non-clustered index is created on it on after the data is inserted.

Comment: In the scenario of the MERGE query, the indexes would exist on both tables BEFORE the MERGE query takes place, whereas with the SELECT INTO case, it's the opposite, the data would be inserted first and then the indexes are created on TableB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will a MERGE between two tables ever be faster than a DROP and SELECT INTO on the second table?

I think, in general, I'd say probably not.  But it depends on a lot of factors.

### Bulk Loading (minimal logging)

`SELECT...INTO` will benefit from bulk load optimizations.  The `INSERT` portion of the `MERGE` query might benefit from these optimizations, but the `UPDATE` portion won't.  So the `MERGE` statement will likely result in more transaction log writes, making it slower.

### DROP vs DELETE

`SELECT...INTO` will also benefit from the fact that `DROP TABLE` is a metadata operation, and thus will "remove" all the rows very quickly.  The `DELETE` portion of the `MERGE` query will be logged normally, resulting in more transaction log writes, making it slower.

### Concurrency

`SELECT...INTO` will benefit from reduced locking / blocking / concurrency issues, because it will have exclusive access to the target table.  The `MERGE` statement will potentially have to deal with lock escalation, blocking by other processes, etc, unless you provide `TABLOCK` hints.

### Index Maintenance

The `MERGE` statement also has to deal with index maintenance (you mentioned there is a clustered index and a nonclustered index on the target table in this scenario), whereas the `SELECT...INTO` does not.  To mitigate this, you could potentially drop the indexes and recreate them after the `MERGE` has run.

### Additional thoughts

All of this somewhat depends on what the breakdown (in terms of # of rows) is between `INSERT`s, `UPDATE`s, and `DELETE`s in the `MERGE` statement, but in general I would expect the `SELECT...INTO` case to be quicker unless the `MERGE` statement has been designed *very* carefully.

Some related information that might be interesting to you and this situation:

- [Why "Select * into targettable from sourcetable “ is faster than “insert into targettable select * from sourcetable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/12818/6141)
- [The Data Loading Performance Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd425070(v=sql.100))

---

Sidebar: in a comment, you mentioned:

> I'm asking because in my case I have to synchronize about 300 million records, and with my testing of only 5 million records, the SELECT INTO took about 30 seconds, the MERGE took about 4 minutes. :(

To compare "apples to apples" make sure to include the time it takes to create the two indexes you mentioned for the `SELECT...INTO` case:

> In my specific case, there's actually no indexes on TableB at the time of the SELECT INTO, but a single unique clustered (PK) and a single non-clustered index is created on it on after the data is inserted. If a MERGE query was used instead, then both tables would have unique clustered indexes and non-clustered indexes on them.